# newly published react module is not getting referred from node_modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I published a new `react/redux` component in `npm`. I created another app using create react app to test whether the newly published npm module is getting imported and working properly but it is not working I'm getting imported and working but it is not working I'm getting error like

> ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve Test in
>   /Users/Vanya/projects/react_app/src

and I've imported like `import * as test from 'Test';`

why the newly published module is not getting referred from `node_modules` instead it is searching in the current project `src` folder. what changes I've to do to make it work properly because all other packages from node_modules is working only this newly published module is not working.

Comment: give the link to newly published npm package